# Updation not update in the front end

Tags: magento-1.9

This is regarding updation for disable the product or any other attribute changes in bulk through Magmi has not been updated in the frontend.

Please help me out to get resolved in the same timing once CSV run through magmi.

Comment: Try to reindex once changes done to see attributes changes.